# Confirmation dialog for Cancel button in sharepoint webpart

Tags: sharepoint, webpart-connection

hi i am creating a webpart. i have a custom toolpart for my webpart. there i'll type some text. when i click save it will print in sharepointpage. when an user click cancel in webpart's toolpart i need to ask confirmation dialog and if the user selects "OK" i need to run some server side code. is it possible. Please help me on that.

Answer (score 2):

In your toolpart register an onsubmit event handler (this will be called on OK/Apply/Cancel or if you do **anything** else that causes a postback)

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Don't run if in SharePoint Designer
        if (ParentToolPane.InCustomToolPane)
            return;

        // Connect to the form Submit event RenderToolPart event is too late,            
        // Putting this in OnLoad event causes javascript error webpart may
        // be loaded for ApplyChanges but not rendered - leading to javascript error
        this.Page.RegisterOnSubmitStatement("submit", "yourCustom_onSubmit();");
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Also be sure to have a javascript `function yourCustom_onSubmit` on your page - putting up a confirmation message and cancelling submit is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. i got what i need.

Comment: Well then start voting and accepting answers Michael - show some thanks for those helping you and you're more likely to get help in future. See FAQ top right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It's like asp.net, so you can insert a Javascript, like the sample we found at [this site](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2004/03/16/178.aspx).

Comment: No. i am asking the event for the button which is in webpart properties. Those buttons (OK, Cancel, Apply) are created by sharepoint not my custom buttons. i need to ask confirmation for that cancel button. your example not suitable for my problem.